Spring-Cloud-Gateway request-header filter not working
I want to remove the authorization-header in spring-cloud-gateway.
Its not possible to do this by spring docs, because the header is readonly. The following code throws an UnexpectedOperationException
filters:
   - AddRequestHeader=X-Custom-Header,CustomValue
   - RemoveRequestHeader=Sensitive-Header

This is a part of my configuration in application.yml.
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: test-route
          uri: http://52.20.148.183
          predicates:
            - Path=/test/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1

With every try, removing the header in code for example with GlobalFilter and exchange.mutate()..., I ran into error.
Only this way by chat-gpt works:
public class CustomRequestDecorator extends ServerHttpRequestDecorator {

    public CustomRequestDecorator(ServerHttpRequest delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.putAll(super.getHeaders());
        headers.remove(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        headers.remove("Postman-Token");
        return headers;
    }
}

@Component
public class RemoveAuthenticationHeaderFilter implements GlobalFilter {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RemoveAuthenticationHeaderFilter.class);
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        logger.info("Removing authentication header");
        var customRequest = new CustomRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest());
        var newExchange = exchange.mutate().request(customRequest).build();
        return chain.filter(newExchange);
    }
}

Did I make a misstake? This is not a good solution for future, because it is not possible, using default filters to mutate request-headers.

Filters should work. have you added  RemoveRequestHeader=Authorization to the Filters config?

In your filter, instead of trying to alter the request, create a copy of it with modified headers.
